# Enabling certain plugins and options for .h and .cpp files only in Vim

Tags: c++, vim, autocomplete, file-type

I have delimitMate installed for brace completion in Vim but it is running for all files, not just .h and .cpp files. DelimitMate has an option for disabling itself in the buffer so I need to add something to my .vimrc that says "disable delimitMate in the buffer of all files except for .h and .cpp files" though I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [DelimitMate](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate) documentation at `:h 'b:delimitMate_autoclose'`. Add the following to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
let g:delimitMate_autoclose = 0
augroup my_delimitmate
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType cpp let b:delimitMate_autoclose = 1
augroup END
```

The idea is to turn off autoclose globally (`g:`) and turn it back on for specific buffers (`b:`).

Instead of the `:autocmd` and `:augroup` commands you can set `b:loaded_delimitMate` inside the appropriate ftplugin file. Example add the following to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim`:

```
let b:delimitMate_autoclose = 1
```

This method might be prefered if you want to keep your `~/.vimrc` file clean or you already have many filetype specific commands, settings, or mappings.

Note: I do not use DelimitMate so I have not tested any of these settings.

For more help see:

```
:h :aug
:h :au
:h FileType
:h 'b:delimitMate_autoclose'
:h delimitMateFileType
:h ftplugin
```

Comment: I think both of you misunderstood me. I only want delimitMate on for .h and .cpp files, nothing else

Comment: I need something like "if FileType cpp == true then continue; else b:loaded_delimitMate = 1"

Comment: You can do that: `autcmd FileType * let b:loaded_delimitMate = &ft != 'cpp'`. However using "off by default" option (`delimitMate_offByDefault`) and turn it on for just cpp gives you options later down the road, as you can easily turn it on for other filetypes by adding another `autcmd FileType ...` line.

Comment: I have changed the post to reflect the turning on for cpp/.h files. However as I noted in the post this may not be the setting you want to use. It may be `b:delimitMate_autoclose` as I have no way to tell. Personally I have ditched the auto closing plugins completely and use [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) now for any of my pair-ing needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is autocommands.  Autocommands can run pieces of vimscript whenever a certain event happens. You can see a list of all possible events by doing `:help autocmd-events`

So according to your needs, first you should disable delimitMate in your vimrc.  Then, you can put something like this in your vimrc (after you disable delimitMate):

```
autocmd FileType cpp (insert command to disable delimitMate here)
```

That way, vim will disable delimitMate by default, but it will enable it if the fieltype is cpp. *(this includes header files)*
Of course, more information is available on the `autocmd` command by doing `:help :autocmd`