# Use all file types but excluding some

Tags: vim, file-type

delimitMate_excluded_ft takes a string of file types to exclude from being used in DelimitMate. I want to set it to all filetypes except cpp, c, and rust files. Can I do something like "*-cpp,-rust" Is there an equivalent to that in vimscript?

Comment: Did you look into: [Enabling certain plugins and options for .h and .cpp files only in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27137310/438329)? Did you read all of DelimitMate's documentation, `:h delimitMate`. Especially the following: `:h 'delimitMate_offByDefault'` and `:h 'b:delimitMate_autoclose'`? What have you tried? Since you are only using DelimitMate for only a few filetypes have you considered getting rid of it and using something like [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround)?

Comment: Surround.vim doesn't seem like it would be useful for C++ or Rust code. 'delimitMate_offByDefault requires you to run DelimitMateSwitch in turn it back on but once you do that it's on for all buffers. I only want DelimitMate to run on C++ and Rust files, which is why I'm trying to make a string containing all of Vim's known filetypes, excluding cpp and rust for delimitmate_excluded_ft so it wont affect anything except cpp and rust files.

Comment: I have broken down and installed delimitMate to test this issue and have solved this problem via the `delimitMate_autoclose` option. Please look at this post: [Enabling certain plugins and options for .h and .cpp files only in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27137310/438329). Let me know if this works for you so I can mark this question as duplicate.

Comment: I believe this should work fine. You can mark it as dupicate.